# Export & Import syntax error with node =>4.6.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, node-modules, es6-modules

Node supports ES6 from node v4.6 upwards, if i'm not mistaken.
Creating ES6 modules works fine until I need to import and export these modules, I then get the following error(s):

```
export class Helper {
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

I feel like I'm missing something.

SOLUTION THAT WORKED FOR ME

in your tsconfig.json file, add the property

```
{"module": "commonjs"}
```

this will keep the ES6 syntax and behaviour but import/export using the ES5 method.

Answer (score -1):

This is what you would want:

```
class name {

 }

module.exports = name;
```